# Java client cannot connect ot Java server, locally, due VPN

Tags: java, web-services, vpn

I have problem to call locally (localhost) webservice from my Java client application to server application running on Java AS (wildfly10).
I used VM argument

> *-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true*

which was advice in other questions. There is VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) running (because there is one more WS that server application calls as client to remote server). The most probably the VPN is cause of my trouble, because without VPN running I am able to call WS. Is there any setting that make this working?

Error in logs:

```
09:34:36,400 [75] ERROR simulator.RequestProcess  - run error  
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect  
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.pair(Unknown Source)
at my.code.simulator.RequestProcess.pair(RequestProcess.java:121)
at my.code.simulator.RequestProcess.run(RequestProcess.java:78)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that WSDL contains my computer alias that was not resolved by DNS (?) in standalone.xml there was

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>0.0.0.0</wsdl-host>
...
```

working after modify to

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:2.0">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>localhost</wsdl-host>
...
```